# Force IDE 2 BETA not working due to java.lang.NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, force.com-ide

I'm using the old eclipse-based Force IDE for some of my task, mostly deployments. I've seen that there is a new BETA Version of Force IDE 2 based on Salesforce DX here: https://developer.salesforce.com/de/tools/forceide2

Today I've downloaded it (for 64-bit Windows). It comes as one ZIP. Pretty straight forward I've unpacked it and run forceide.exe. I'm on a Windows 7 64bit machine.

I think there is not much room for doing this wrong.

Then it's raining errors

**On Startup**

[image]

**On SFDX Project**

[image]

**My Java JRE is**

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)

**Question**

Any idea on what I can try to overcome this issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if you (like me) are not reading the instructions carefully ;-)

As a prerequisite you need to download and install Salesforce CLI like stated here

> **Salesforce CLI**
>
> Each Force.com IDE 2 version depends on a matched version of the
>   Salesforce CLI. Install the Salesforce CLI and its prerequisites
>   before installing Force.com IDE
>
> For Salesforce CLI installation instructions, see “System
>   Requirements” and “Install the Salesforce Command Line Interface
>   (CLI)” in the Salesforce DX Setup Guide (Beta).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_ide2.meta/sfdx_ide2/sfdx_ide2_get_started_prerequisites.htm

After that all errors disappeared.

Comment: Maybe to put on the "wishlist": IDE 2 should get an installer and it should check for the prerequisites and install them in case they are missing. Will save us from this mistakes. Usually we devs don't read much in advance...